# How to Apply Changes to GPO without Restarting Server?

Tags: windows-server

I use [LGPO tool](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/secguide/2016/01/21/lgpo-exe-local-group-policy-object-utility-v1-0/) to apply changes to GPO. But for changes to take effect, server needs to be reapplied. Any possibility of applying changes without restart?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server administration questions belong on [sf] or [su] instead. (Many GPO policies require a restart in order to take effect, and if it requires a restart it requires a restart. There's no magic spell that says *Take this policy change that requires a restart and make it work without that restart*.)

Comment: @KenWhite, there is a Windows-Server tag, out of curiosity -- what programming questions can be asked on Windows Server?

Comment: That tag is a remnant from before [sf] was created. It's still here for historic reasons, because there are older posts that are tagged with it. There are dozens (if not hundreds) of tags that are no longer valid because new sites exist for those topics now. The current guidelines can be found in the [help].